# Eclipse CDT compile static lib with main project compiler settings

Tags: c++, c, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ embedded project with mixed C project that uses 2 static libraries (inside static library projects).

The static libraries require some symbols that changes for each target board, but at this point it looks like I can only set the compiler settings/symbols per project.

Is there any way I can make the static library recompile everytime the main application compiler settings/symbols changes?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can make the static library recompile everytime the main application compiler settings/symbols changes?

I think you are looking at this back to front. **Instead of trying to rebuild the static library every time - build two static libraries**. Even if the two libraries share the same code, the fact that they contain different symbols or some fundamental variation for each target board makes them two separate libraries that need to be built. The same would be applicable for the projects as a whole.

A similar situation is seen on the PC side as well - x86 vs. x64 as typical targets. The same project can be used to manage the code, but there are two distinct target platforms - when you build for both, you cannot share the same physical static libraries. Any static libraries you depend on are built to target each platform - hence the "x86" version of the library and the "x64" version.

Comment: I agree with you and usually I use makefiles to change this flags as needed, but now I have to use Eclipse for developing and testing for several boards and having a different version for each target it's a lot. Guess that there is no other way with Eclipse. NEw project + Import main project settings will do the trick for now

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this is supported in Eclipse, but I would imagine there is some variation of "multi-platform" support etc. You can look into that. Failing that, you can use the same mechanism that fuels Debug vs. Release builds. Add a Platform1_Release, Platform2_Release etc. as targets and given them the appropriate compiler flags, separate build and output locations etc. Then "rebuild all"...